# Create Centerlines of a Polygon Buffer Feature, ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, buffer, arcgis-10.3

I have seen another method for this to create centerlines, but that involved splitting the line and deleting the line closures. This is a huge network and the time involved in that would be impossible.I was hoping there was another method that I could not find that someone would help me out with, possibly new with 10.3.
I have ArcMap Advanced with Spatial Analysis and 3D Analyst extensions.
Example of part of network below.
[image: Network]

Comment: Did you try the Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline tool?  You would first convert your polygons to lines.  You might see if you can symbolize your polygons as a single black color, export that to a georeferenced raster, then run Arcscan on it to get lines.

Comment: Ya the problem with the Collapse Duel Lines tool is I'd have to delete the endpoints to make sure they are open lines and there are 1000's of them :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bc642731870740aabf48134f90aa6165) will accomplish what you are trying to do.

From description:

"Converts closed polygons (commonly used for representing roads and rivers) to centerlines using the Thiessen polygon method. There is a Densify Distance parameter that you will likely need to adjust to optimize your results. Some post-processing editing is probably also required to ensure that lines connect properly..."

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did try this tool, but I was receiving this error. It could possibly be because i'm using 10.3 and the tool wasn't updated. ERROR 000261: Cannot add point features to TIN
Failed to execute (Create Thiessen Polygons).

Comment: I was under the impression that toolboxes for 10.1 worked for 10.2 and 10.3. Take a look at that error code here: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=tool_errors_and_warnings:251-275   It looks like it has more to do with locations/workspaces/naming more than anything else. Have you renamed the buffer layer you are working with in the TOC? That is a common culprit for these errors. I was going to test it on my machine but it requires a higher license level than I currently have installed. Good Luck.

Comment: When you say renaming it what do you exactly mean. I did look at the error message. I have moved the scratch workspace everywhere even to the root drive and still getting the error. I also made sure the folder had "everyone" permissions. Ugh...

Comment: I am referring to renaming your feature in the table of contents in the .mxd you are working out of.

Comment: Ahh no, I was loading them from the file explorer option instead of dragging. I always figure that is a safer way to do it.