# Generating centerline of a polygon feature, extending line feature - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, intersection, extend

I am attempting to generate centerlines of polygon features using Polygon to Centerline in ArcGIS Pro. My goal in this effort is to create a straight line directly through the center of the feature. I have thoroughly researched this question and have tried multiple solutions listed in other threads with no successful outcome. My workflow so far involved an intersect operation on a building footprint layer (resulting in line features), then generating a 5-foot buffer around the results of the intersection.

I will attach an image of my Polygon to Centerline results below:

[image: The result of a Polygon to Centerline operation on a 5-foot buffer]

As you can see above, the resulting centerlines are not directly following the middle of the polygon features, rather, the centerline is curving at one or both of the ends. I have tried densifying the buffers before running Polygon to Centerline and running [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157148/create-centerlines-of-a-polygon-buffer-feature-arcgis-10-3) tool, both of which have resulting in curved lines.

Below I will attach an image of what I would like for this operation to produce:

[image: Desired results]

In a more general sense, I am looking to extend the resulting lines of the intersect operation without manual effort. I will insert a picture of the intersect results, and about where I would like for them to extend to.

[image: How can I extend these lines?]

How can I get these lines to extend further without curving or changing the general orientation?

***Edit for Solution:*** Please see Hornbydd's comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the buffers are constantly what you have shown, the blue "pill shape" then you could explore using the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool using the `rectangle_by_width` option.  Then extract the centreline of that and feed that into the [Extend Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/extend-line.htm) tool if your data and license allows it.

****Update (taken from comment below):****

To expand on the logic above, this is what I am suggesting.

1. Split the rectangle by its vertices to create four lines.
2. take the two shortest, get their centroids.
3. connect those two points, that would give you your centreline of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This seems to have gotten me closer to the answer, but sadly the centerline is still skewed towards the end of the line geometry. Luckily, it seems that only one end of the line is having this problem as opposed to both ends, so that is a great improvement in my mind! I am going to test the Extend Line tool more to see if I can get the features to extend directly through that tool.

Comment: You could think out the box... Split the rectangle by its vertices to create four lines, take the two shortest, get their centroid and then connect those two points, that would give you your centreline of the rectangle.

Comment: That is a great idea! I will give that a try!

Comment: Thank you so much, that gave me exactly what I was looking for. I marked your first comment as the answer to this thread. I appreciate the help!